# RedirectToAction inside a method doesn't work

Tags: actionresult, redirecttoaction

Hello i have this method

```
private ActionResult CheckResult(ReactivationResponse result, GlobalObject globalInfo)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Failed", "Redirect", new { errorCode = 1014 });
        }
        else if (!result.IsReactivationSuccess && !result.IsOrderImported && !globalInfo.MemberInfo.IsWinbackAplicable)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Failed", "Redirect", new { errorCode = 201 });
        }
        else if (!result.IsReactivationSuccess && result.Errors.Any())
        {
            if (result.Errors.Any(e => e.Message == "ApprovalPending"))
            {
                return View("Pending");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Failed", "Redirect", new { errorCode = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault().StackTrace });
        }
        return null;
    }
```

inside another Action Result

```
public ActionResult OtherMethod()
{
    CheckResult(result, globalInfo);
    //More code
    return View()
}
```

I'm trying to redirect the code according to the result, and in case it doesn't apply, that the app continue and return the normal view.

But it doesn't work, if any of the if statements applies it doesn't redirect to anywhere, it continues with the normal viw.

I also tried to put a return before the method

```
return CheckResult(result, globalInfo);
```

and it works except if my method returns null, then it doesn't continue with the app.

I want to evaluate if it needs to redirect or if it should continue

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints to see if the flow is even making it to the methods? When you add them, check to see if the result and globalInfo variables contain what you expect.

Comment: Yes, it enters the method, and i tried various cases, sending the result null, or with an error, it goes to the redirectToAction, and if outside i have a `return CheckResult(result, globalInfo);` it redirects to where i desire, but the problem it's when this methods returns null, i breaks the continuity, or without the return i doesn't do anything